# C++ polymorphism. Methods

Tags: c++, class, methods, polymorphism

I have a small problem which I can't handle.
Currently I'm working over a project about a marathon between animals.
I'm obliged to use polymorphism even though it could be easier without.
Here's a sample of my code:

```
class Animal 
{
public:
virtual void run()=0;
virtual bool return_if_finished()=0;
virtual float return_distance()=0;
}
class Turtle :public Animal
{
 int id;
 float distance; //etc.
 public:
 void run();
 bool return_if_finished();
 float return_distance();
 void set_id(int i);
 void a_friend();
}
class Snail :public Animal
{
 float distance; //etc.
 public:
 void run();
 bool return_if_finished();
 float return_distance();
 void broken_leg();
}
```

So that's a sample. All classes that inherit from the main class "Animal" have only three mutual methods. They also have some that only they do need.

If I want to write a code in a method where they "run" like that:

```
...
Animal* turtles = new Turtle[amount];
Animal* snails = new Snail[amount];
for(int i=0; i<amount; i++)
    turtles[i].set_id(i);
```

I can't compile it because "class Animal has no member called "set_id"".
I could create all these methods for each class but that would be totally pointless. I bet there's a quick solution to that.
If I create a virtual void "set_id(int)" for the class "Animal" then I get the error message that not all classes that inherit from animal contain that method.
So any help would be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You need to have an Animal pointer, and dereference it to achieve polymorphic behaviour. Furthermore, you need to actually construct these before using.

Comment: You should use pointers to `Animal` if you want to benefit the polymorphism, otherwise the C++ compiler will link all method calls to the ones from `Animal`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all, using:

```
Animal* turtles = new Turtle[amount];
Animal* snails = new Snail[amount];
```

is a bad idea.

The pointer arithmetic on `turtles` and `snails` will be based size of `Animal`. If you use `tutles[i]` for all `i` not equal to `0`, you'll run into undefined behavior. There is probably an SO question somewhere about that.

Use a `vector` of pointers instead. It will be also easier to initialize them.

```
std::vector<Animal*> turtles(amount); = new Turtle[amount];
for(int i=0; i<amount; i++)
{
    Turtle* tptr = new Turtle;
    tptr->set_id(i);
    turtles[i] = tptr;
}
```

Better yet, use a smart pointer.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> turtles(amount); = new Turtle[amount];
for(int i=0; i<amount; i++)
{
    Turtle* tptr = new Turtle;
    tptr->set_id(i);
    turtles[i] = std::shared_ptr<Animal>(tptr);
    // Or 
    // turtles[i].reset(tptr);
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use a unqiue_ptr.

Comment: This code can not compile, by the way. You can not assign shared_ptr to Turtle*.

Answer (score 2):

> If I create a virtual void "set_id(int)" for the class "Animal" then I get the error message that not all classes that inherit from animal contain that method.

I suspect you defined Animal::set_id as a **pure** virtual, like this:

```
virtual void set_id(int) = 0;
```

What you really want is to define it in the `Animal` class as a virtual method, like this:

```
virtual void set_id(int _id) {id = _id};
```

Also, the `id` member variable needs to be moved to the `Animal` class instead of `Turtle`

**EDIT:**

Expanding the answer to include the full code:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() : id(-1) {}
    virtual ~Animal() {}

    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual bool return_if_finished() = 0;
    virtual float return_distance() = 0;

    void set_id(int i) { id = i; }

private: 
    int id;
};

class Turtle :public Animal
{
public:
    void run() {};
    bool return_if_finished() { return true; };
    float return_distance() { return 2.0; };
    void a_friend() {};
};

class Snail :public Animal
{
public:
    void run() {};
    bool return_if_finished() { return false; };
    float return_distance() { return 1.0; };
    void broken_leg() {};
};


int main()
{
    const int amount = 10;
    Turtle turtles[amount];
    Snail snails[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        turtles[i].set_id(i);
    }
}
```